# How to get the attribute of the root element of the xml file in python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing

I am trying to count the total number of an attribute in an XML file. I tried to do this, everything worked fine but I stuck on one problem that I don't know to get the attribute of the root element I tried to do lots of things but nothing worked

---------x here is my code snippet x -----------

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# getting the xml file from input
xml = ''.join([input()+'\n' for _ in range(int(input()))])
score = 0            # counting total attribute

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for child in tree:
    score += len(child.attrib)

print(score)
```

its output is 4 instead of 5

----------x The XML file that I used as input x-------------------

```xml
6
<feed xml:lang='en'>
    <title>HackerRank</title>
    <subtitle lang='en'>Programming challenges</subtitle>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://hackerrank.com/'/>
    <updated>2013-12-25T12:00:00</updated>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the tree's root attrib to the score

```
if len(tree.attrib):
   score += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This code only counts the attributes in Child and the attributes in the tree should be added to it with:

```
score += len(tree.attrib)
```